# Is it possible to change width of notification tray area on Windows 2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, notification-area

I have a particular setup where a specific program installed gets minimized to the notification area. I would like this to always be visible (along with several others). Regardless of whether I hide notifcations for certain programs, the system chooses not display a particular one unless I click on the double chevron up arrow. Is there a way to just force the tray area to larger size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tick the checkbox `Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar` to show them **all**, and as far as I know it doesn't have a maximum size (if it doesn't fit however, make the taskbar bigger in height to fit more icons).

The checkbox can be found by clicking on the `double chevron up arrow` > `Customize` > at the bottom of the window

OR

`Start` > `Control Panel` > `Notification Area Icons`

Comment: This seems to be the best approach - change it to "always show all icons",which makes the notification area much bigger.  Then turn off "always show", and turn on the ones that you want to see - the larger notification area remains.